# Problem with character input by getchar() or getche()

Tags: c

When I compile the C codes (from *Teach yourself C, 2nd edition-Herbert Schildt*) written below in Borland C++ v5.02, I get a warning message as below:
"c61.c(7,6): Conversion may lose significant digits"

What's wrong?

```
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{
 char ch;
 ch = getchar();
 printf(" You typed: %c", ch);

 return 0;
}
```

Same problem with another example:

```
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{
 char ch;

 printf("Enter a character: ");
 ch = getche();
 printf("\nIts ASCII code is %d", ch);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're _still_ using char in your second example!

Answer (score 6):

getchar() returns an int, so that it can return non-character values like EOF. So when you store the return value in a smaller datatype, like a char, you are potentially losing information.

Schildt's books are commonly considered the worst available for learning C (or C++) and this is a good example of why. You would be well advised to get a better book, such as K&R.

Comment: yes, most of the example I've tested dont working.The third edition of this book claims it has been sold over 150,000 copies though.

Comment: @Sharifhs: Schildt's books have very bad reputation. [ACCU](http://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search) don't have a review of your book, but you can get an idea from their reviews of Schildt's other books. See http://c-faq.com/resources/books.html for pointers to better books. K&R is excellent, though not really suitable if C is your first programming language.

Comment: Dear Neil, I regret that I don't really understand the explanation. I can't understand the term "return" you used here. What does mean by "getchar() returns an int"?

Comment: @Sharifhs the book must be *really* bad if it doesn't cover the concept of return values of functions. In your code, you are storing the returned value in a char, but you need to store it in an int to get rid of the compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for `getchar` is:

```
int getchar (void);
```

It returns an `int` because it needs to return EOF which is not a character.

---

Expanding on that, the function needs to be able to return *any* valid character, as well as being able to return a special "character" indicating that you're reached the end of file (or an error has occurred).

Since a `char` data type can only hold one of the characters, there would be no way to indicate this end of file if all the function returned was a `char`. That's because, if you selected one of those `char` values to represent end of file, you would not be able to tell the difference between the end of file and the actual character.

For example, let's choose 'A' to indicate end of file. When you actually get back an 'A' from `getchar()`, how will you know whether you've reached the end of file or whether the user actually entered 'A'?

To get around this, many functions that give you back a `char` will actually give you an `int` and use one of the integer values which don't have an actual `char` equivalent (such as -1).

In that case (assuming an 8-bit `char`), you would get back either a -1 if you've reached the end of the file or a value from 0 through 255 inclusive representing the character entered.

---

And you need to get yourself both a more modern book *and* a more modern compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int ch = getchar();
    if (ch != EOF)
        printf("You typed: %c\n", ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Why anyone is still using Borland is this day and age (where gcc is both just as cheap and *much* better) is beyond me.

Comment: Works fine for me with gcc. Keep in mind that you may be in cooked input mode. That means you may have to hit enter after your keypress.

Comment: @gordon: why? The only thing that will tell you is if you've _already_ hit end of file before entering `getchar()`. You'll _still_ have to check for EOF from `getchar()` itself since the end of file may happen while you're in there. And, if feof(stdin) is true, you'll _still_ get EOF out of `getchar()` either because of end of file or error trying to read past end of file. It seems you're introducing a check for no real benefit. I could be wrong however, it wouldn't be the first or last time :-)

Comment: Dear paxdiablo, I regret that I don't really understand the explanation. What does mean by "returns a value/int" and EOF?

Comment: paxdiablo, your answer was so valuable though it takes huge time to grasp for me. I kept reading those answers and just now your answer becomes clear to me. Thanks a million for your nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

What about this alternative program? It works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
 char ch;

 getchar();

 printf("Enter the character: ");
 scanf("%c", &ch);
 printf(" You typed: %c\n", ch);
 return 0;
}
```

Please leave some comments.